# Angular2 CLI - how to debug using .ts files

Tags: debugging, angular, angular-cli

I am starting to use Angular2 CLI and now I realize that I do not find the nice *.ts files (among the sources shown in the browser) which makes total sense since CLI moves only *.js

The point though is: how can I continue to use *.ts (while debugging) if I use Angular2 CLI?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be resolved with the beta 5 release. Thanks to this commit: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/234de2b4f91b9b980ff3c55ea4eddabe4db64aa1